# Javascript Sorting Multidimensional array using index

Tags: javascript, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am having issues on identifying the actually index of the array its being sorted.

My list is a bit messy:

```
    masterList =[];
    masterList.push([1,"NY","New York, NY 10036, United States",40.760262,-73.993286,"07/30/2015"]);
    masterList.push([2,"Chgo","Chicago, IL, United States",41.878113,-87.629799,"07/06/2015"]);
    masterList.push([3,"Japan","Japan",11.1111,-11.1111,"07/22/2015"]);
    masterList.push([4,"China","China",22.2222,-22.2222,"07/18/2015"]);

masterList.sort(sortdates());

function sortdates(a,b) {
        return function(a, b){
                a = Date(a[5]);
                console.log(a);
                b = Date(b[5]);
                return a - b;
            };
}
```

Obviously this isn't working. I want to be able to grab the 6st index on the multidimensional array and sort by that.

I tried looking everywhere.. but I don't have a "key" that ties to my array.. so I can't really use that to point it.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Instead of `masterList.sort(sortdates())` you have to write `masterList.sort(sortdates)`. You have to provide a reference to a function, not call the sort-function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three problems.  First, you should pass a function handle to the sort function.  You are calling the function instead. Second, the function should not return a function and should accept two parameters.  Third and most important, you need to create `new` instances of the date object.  It's not a static method.

The returning a function could work, so the real problem you have is the lack of the `new` keyword

```
    masterList =[];
    masterList.push([1,"NY","New York, NY 10036, United States",40.760262,-73.993286,"07/30/2015"]);
    masterList.push([2,"Chgo","Chicago, IL, United States",41.878113,-87.629799,"07/06/2015"]);
    masterList.push([3,"Japan","Japan",11.1111,-11.1111,"07/22/2015"]);
    masterList.push([4,"China","China",22.2222,-22.2222,"07/18/2015"]);

masterList.sort(sortdates);

function sortdates(a,b) {
                a = new Date(a[5]);
                console.log(a);
                b = new Date(b[5]);
                return a - b;
}
```

Comment: thanks! hmm I put in console.log(masterList), but nothing is happening.. the array doesn't seemed to be sorted?

Comment: @SQLNub It seems to sort.  I'll put together a better demo.

Comment: it is sorted! ya i think i forgot the new part. Thank you!

Comment: @SQLNub aw dang it... I just finished it too. :P  http://jsfiddle.net/nrf5e8hc/  Oh well.  Glad the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've got an extra function in there. This would work better, no need to return another function.

```
function sortdates(a,b) {
    a = new Date(a[5]);
    console.log(a);
    b = new Date(b[5]);
    return a - b;
}
```

Then you can pass `sortdates` (without the `()`) to sort

Comment: I just tried using your suggested code in combination of without (), then console.log(masterList); shortly after .sort... doesn't seem to be reflecting the new array?

Answer (score -1):

How about using underscore.js?

Then you can use [sortBy](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy) as follows:

```
var sorted = _.sortBy(masterList, function(value){ return new Date(value[5]).getTime(); });
```

[Here is a fiddle with the solution](https://jsfiddle.net/peczq5h2/)